# How to calculate overall score based on columns values?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, choice-field

I am seeking for help with SharePoint online list, where I have choice columns with following answer choices: 1,2,3,4,5 where each choice has own value e.g.

- 1 = 30 points
- 2 = 60 points
- 3 = 90 points
- 4 = 120 points
- 5 = 150 points

How do I write the formula for calculated column (new column) to show the right value for selected choice?

Comment: If my answer did help you out, please also mark it as an Accepted Answer. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using multiple choice columns like this? What do you mean by "calculate overall score based on columns values"? Are you trying get total points based on single choice column or based on multiple choice columns?

Comment: Did you try using below formula? Is it working for you?

Comment: Have you tried the method below? Does it meet your requirements?

Answer (score 2):

Use this calculated formula, assuming *Choice* is your column name

```
=Choice*30
```

If you need the " points" appended,

```
=CONCATENATE((Choice*30)," points")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Extending answer by [@thebernardlim](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/45134/thebernardlim) further,

If you have multiple choice columns with the choices like: 1,2,3,4,5 and you want to get the overall score (your question title mentions it) based on these columns values (SUM), you can use formula like below for your calculated column:

```
=CONCATENATE([Choice1]*30 + [Choice2]*30 + [Choice3]*30," points")
```

Sometimes, you may need to explicitly convert number choice options to actual number value using `VALUE()` function like:

```
=CONCATENATE(VALUE([Choice1])*30 + VALUE([Choice2])*30 + VALUE([Choice3])*30," points")
```

**Column Settings**:

[image]

**Output**:

[image]

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Use correct *display name* of your SharePoint columns in above formula.
3. Wrap column names inside `[]` if your column name has space in it. For example: `[Choice Column 5]`

**Official Documentations**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14))